# Universal link works in xcode8 simulator but not on ios 10 device

Tags: ios, xcode8, ios-universal-links

Recently I upgraded to xcode 8. I have universal links configured and used to work fine until I released a newer version built on xcode 8.

Surprisingly, universal link works when I am testing in simulator - I can press right corner, then it opens in Safari - again I press right corner, it shows me OPEN banner which opens the app. Also clicking on URL embedded in email works.

However I can't open any of my links in app on my device. My app name is `kabuter` and apple-app-site-association file is at `https://www.kabuter.com/.well-known`

I checked and confirmed that my app build contains entitlement file (which contains applinks entries).

In apple appsearch-validation-tool, I am getting:

> Link to Application
>
> ACTION REQUIRED
>
> Could not extract required information for Universal Links. Learn how to implement the recommendedUniversal Links.
>
> Extracted Data
>
> Error no apps with domain entitlements
>      The entitlement data used to verify deep link dual authentication is from the current released version of your app. This data may take 48 hours to update.

branch.io validator https://branch.io/resources/universal-links/ passes all tests.

I am also seeing this in my log when I connect my device to xcode:

```
logging for process kabuter

2016-10-12 19:48:27.247786 kabuter[619:90471] WF: _userSettingsForUser mobile: {

    filterBlacklist =     (
    );

    filterWhitelist =     (
    );

    restrictWeb = 1;

    useContentFilter = 0;

    useContentFilterOverrides = 0;

    whitelistEnabled = 0;

}

2016-10-12 19:48:27.248052 kabuter[619:90471] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
```

Has anyone encountered this issue and found solution? Any pointers?

Comment: For me the cause was that I had used the wrong App Prefix ID in my apple-app-site-association file - I'd used the Team ID but that wasn't correct apparently. Apple pointed me towards this piece of documentation for how to find the correct App Prefix ID: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1798/_index.html

Comment: @donlys How do you test the universal link in the simulator? Do you paste the link in safari?

Comment: @ricardopereira - yes copy from email and paste in safari

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you may have inadvertently disabled Universal Links on that device. Fortunately it's fairly simple to re-enable them:

1. Get a Universal Links URL
2. Paste that URL into Notes
3. Long-press on the URL and select 'Open in [app name]'

Comment: I have tried that - I am not seeing the Open in kabuter on device. I do however see that option when in simulator.

Comment: Even if you have completely removed the app from your device and reinstall it? Do you have a second device you can try?

Comment: Reinstall did not solve it. I will try it on another device. Do you know what this message from apple validation site mean: Error no apps with domain entitlements ? May be with XCode 8 somehow my target package is messed up?

Comment: Okay - so finally I opened a ticket with Apple. They also could not find anything wrong as well. I then updated my two devices to ios 10.1 and that update got the universal link + banner working on my devices. I have no logical explanation. Possibly something with ios 10.0.x or issue in general with devices that are used for xcode testing. Just wanted to post this comment for any future reference.